# Computing the double integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

How can I compute this integral?

$$\int _0 ^{\infty} \int _0 ^{\infty }\frac { 4xy-x^2-y^2}{(x+y)^4}dx dy$$

I tried polar coordinate, but it didn't work.

Would anyone please give me a hint?

Thanks for your help and advice.

Comment: Go polar coordinates. The region of integration is in the first quadrant. So you can imagine a circle with radius from 0 to infinity, and angle from 0 to pi/2

Comment: @cgo yes I tried that, but it was still hard to compute. Would you please help me more?

Comment: As a Lebesgue double integral, it diverges because $\int 1/r\; dr$ diverges.  But in polar coordinates the integral over $\theta$ is $0$.  I'm not sure what happens as an iterated improper integral in $x$ and $y$.

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Do you think this user knows about Lebesgue?

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE of course I know.

Comment: Just pointing out that this is a delicate problem, and change of variables is not justified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u=x+y$, so $x = u-y$.

$$
\begin{align*}
&\int _0 ^{\infty} \int _y ^{\infty}\frac { 4(u-y)y-(u-y)^2-y^2}{u^4}du\ dy\\
&=\int _0 ^{\infty} \int _y ^{\infty }4yu^{-3}-4y^2u^{-4}-u^{-2}+2yu^{-3}-y^2u^{-4}-y^2u^{-4}  \ du\ dy\\
&=\int _0 ^{\infty} \int _y ^{\infty }6yu^{-3}-6y^2u^{-4}-u^{-2}  \ du\ dy\\
&=\int _0 ^{\infty} -3yu^{-2}+2y^2u^{-3}+u^{-1} \bigg|_y^\infty\ dy \\
&=\int _0 ^{\infty} 3y^{-1}-2y^{-1}-y^{-1} \ dy \\
&=\int _0 ^{\infty} 0\ dy\\
&= 0
\end{align*}
$$

This matches [Wolfram's answer.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427euhijqbmgld)

Comment: Oops... just saw the comments about how a change of variable is not justified. Perhaps someone can point out the error for posterity's sake.

Comment: Change of variables for the inner ($x$) integral is OK, and does give $0$.
Change to polar (or other) coordinates would be problematic.

Comment: Interesting... Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try the partial fraction expansion $$\begin{align}
\frac{4xy-x^2-y^2}{(x+y)^4} & = \frac{6xy-(x+y)^2}{(x+y)^4}
\\[1ex] & = \frac{-6y^2}{(x+y)^4}+\frac{6y(x+y)}{(x+y)^4} - \frac{(x+y)^2}{(x+y)^4}
\\[1ex]& =  \frac{-6y^2}{(x+y)^4}+\frac{6y}{(x+y)^3} - \frac{1}{(x+y)^2}
\end{align}$$